# Weird execution of a Mono Sequence in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a scenario where I am calling a method inside Mono sequence, depending on the way I am calling the sequence, I either get an error or the sequence is successful.

**Successful sequence:**

```
    @Override
    public Mono<User> getUserDetails(String userId) {
        return reactiveValueOps
            .get(userId)
            .switchIfEmpty(userService.getUser(Long.valueOf(userId))
                .flatMap(this::setUserDetails));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<User> setUserDetails(User user) {
        return reactiveValueOps
            .set(String.valueOf(user.getId()), user, Duration.ofDays(SESSION_PERSISTENCE_DURATION))
            .flatMap(b -> Mono.just(user));
    }
```

**Error Sequence:**

```
    @Override
    public Mono<User> getUserDetails(String userId) {
        return reactiveValueOps
            .get(userId)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                Mono<User> user = userService.getUser(Long.valueOf(userId));
                Mono<Boolean> valueSet = setUserDetails(user);
                return valueSet.zipWith(user, (v, u) -> u);
            }));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Boolean> setUserDetails(Mono<User> user) {
        return user.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() ->
            Mono.error(new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot persist empty User Object"))))
            .flatMap(u -> reactiveValueOps.set(String.valueOf(u.getId()), u, Duration.ofDays(1L)));
    }
```

`userService.getUser` method either returns the user from DB or creates a new user getting details from 3rd party APIs, in 2nd sequence I get this error:

`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`
This error only happens if the user is not already present in the DB, no issue if its in the database and only for the second execution flow.
Does something wrong happen when I use `zipWith`?

Comment: Is something extra or some code snipped required here?